# Como calcular o DigestValue do XML?

Tags: java, xml, base64, sha1

Ao assinar algum XML, o assinador gera a tag DigestValue contendo uma Hash. 
Eu consigo gerar o digest value com um certificado digital, mas eu gostaria de gerar essa hash sem que tenha a necessidade de um certificado...

Eu vi em algumas documentações, que é necessário utilizar SHA1 e Base64, mas sempre que eu utilizo esses dois algoritmos, a hash que me retorna não é a que eu estou esperando.

**Alguém sabe qual o algoritmo completo para gerar esse valor?**

**Cenário:**

- Entrada é um XML qualquer
- Utilizo o algoritmo de criptografia SHA1, em seguida
- Transformo o retorno da criptografia em Base64
- O retorno da base64 deveria ser a hash correta, porém vem uma hash diferente.

Comment: Como é o código que você usa para gerar e comparar o hash? Pode postar-lo? É difícil saber o que está errado sem saber exatamente como você o fez.

Comment: Eu gostaria de saber qual o algoritmo para gerar essa hash... Vou editar a pergunta descrevendo os passos que faço.

Comment: Faltou um passo importante que é canonizar o XML. Recomendo o uso da classe [Canonicalizer](http://santuario.apache.org/Java/api/org/apache/xml/security/c14n/Canonicalizer.html) do projeto [Apache Santuario](http://santuario.apache.org/) (na verdade, eu não faria nada na mão, usaria essa biblioteca para tudo). Sobre o algoritmo basta aplicar um SHA1 para obter os bits (não a assinatura em HEX) e, em cima desses bits obter a Base64 da assinatura. A biblioteca [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) tem tudo que você precisa para a segunda parte.

Comment: É para codificar em SHA1 e conveter em base64 eu utilizo essas bibliotecas que você citou.

Answer (score 2):

O processo de se calcular o `DigestValue` de um arquivo XML não se resume a calcular o hash desse arquivo, mas possui outros passos intermediários:

1. Colocar o documento na forma canônica, tal como apontado por @Anthony Accioly;
2. Aplicar quaisquer transformações especificadas em `Reference/Transforms`. Se não há nenhum elemento `Transforms`, ou o mesmo está vazio (sem sub-elementos), então nada precisa ser feito.

Certifique-se que esses passos foram corretamente adotados e, se ainda tiver problemas em conseguir um resultado correto, acrescente mais detalhes à sua pergunta de modo a podermos ajudar mais (se possível mostrando o `SignedInfo` que quer atingir, um link para o arquivo XML e uma descrição dos passos e ferramentas que utilizou).

Nota: minha resposta anterior (em arquivo) não se aplica aqui, pois de fato o `DigestValue` é um simples hash e não uma assinatura digital (portanto invariante à presença ou não de um certificado).

Comment: Huum, obrigado pela resposta. Eu falei que é um digestvalue diferente pois eu já possuo o XML contendo o digestvalue correto e eu preciso de uma função que gere esse digestValue. O DigestValue é independente do certificado, pois eu consigo gerar o digestvalue sem que eu tenha o certificado.

Comment: @fymoribe Pelo que estou lendo, você tem razão, `DigestValue` é uma coisa e `SignatureValue` é outra... Mas ainda não consegui entender exatamente o que ele é, nem qual seu propósito. Vou investigar mais um pouco, se descobrir algo atualizo minha resposta.

Comment: Realmente faltou canonizar a string antes de fazer a criptografia, muito obrigado.

Comment: fymoribe, não se esqueça de aceitar a resposta ;)